# Write same amount of parquet data using sparksql and pyarrow, the output file size of sparksql is much larger

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, pyarrow

I use sparksql and pyarrow separately to get 30 million pieces of the same data, and output the file in parquet format. The file size of sparksql is 4.1G, and the file size of pyarrow is 0.9G. Why the big difference? I assume sparksql output file contains more original data information or index information?

Comment: What is the output format of spark sql ? Is it parquet ?

Comment: yes @VincentDoba
The whole process is to read the file on S3, and then output the file in parquet format to S3

Comment: Have you tried comparing the files using `parquet-tools meta ...`?

Comment: I use `parquet-tools meta ...` to view the parquet using sparksql, found the offset **DO** always start from zero, and the parquet file offset **DO** using pyarrow  is continuous @mazaneicha

Comment: I think you would be more interested in compression algo and `SZ:<compressed/uncompressed/ratio>` displayed by parquet-tools for each column.